# Implementing Double Buffering in Java

Tags: java, graphics, doublebuffered

I have a simple Java JFrame canvas. I am updating what is on the screen every half second or so, and have flickering. I want to implement double buffering to eliminate the flickering, but I am fairly new to Java and am unfamiliar with how to do so. I have found some examples, but not sure how to implement their methods into mine.

Below is the basic setup of how I have things now. This is not my exact code- just an example of the basic setup.

Thanks for any push in the right direction!

```
public class myCanvas extends Canvas{
    //variables
    Color rectColor=Color.red;

    public myCanvas()
    {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        //initial setup, such as
        graphics.setColor(rectColor);
        graphics.fillRect(X,Y,W,H);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myCanvas canvas = new myCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while(true){
            rectColor=Color.green;
            canvas.validate();
            canvas.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid mixing heavy- and lightweight components (AWT and SWING), mostly because they use very different methods of drawing to the display (read [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) if you want to know more).

So instead of the `Canvas`, you could use a `JPanel`. This also gives you a potential solution, because `JPanel` has a method `setDoubleBuffered(boolean)`, more specifically, this is implemented in the `JComponent` class.

I believe it would be sufficient to just replace

```
public class myCanvas extends Canvas
```

by

```
public class myCanvas extends JPanel
```

. Although I haven't tested this, I hope it helps you!

EDIT:
Also, of course, when setting up your `frame` and `canvas` in the `main` method, you'd have to place the method call

```
canvas.setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

somewhere.

Comment: WOW, that worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick response and for a fast, simple solution!\