# I need help understanding how to write the code for double buffering in java applets

Tags: java, applet, doublebuffered

I understand the logic behind it, but don't know how to translate that to code. Could someone please show me on this example that I wrote?

All the applet does is that the center rectangle moves up, down, right and left of its own accord. I want to get rid of the annoying flicker with a double buffer, but I don't know what change/add to make that happen.

```
import java.applet.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Broadway extends Applet implements Runnable {

Thread animation;

int locx,locy; // location of rectangle
int width, height; // dimensions of rectangle

// direction of motion
static final byte UP = 0; 
static final byte DOWN = 1;
static final byte LEFT = 2;
static final byte RIGHT = 3;

byte state; // state the rect is in

// length of pausing interval in ms
static final int REFRESH_RATE = 100;


public void init() {

    setBackground(Color.black);

    locx = 80; // parameters of center rect
    locy = 100;
    width = 110;
    height = 90;
    state = UP;
}

public void start() {

    animation = new Thread(this);

    if (animation != null) {
    animation.start();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(0,0,90,90);
    g.fillRect(250,0,40,190);
    g.fillRect(80,110,100,20);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(80,200,220,90);
    g.fillRect(100,10,90,80);

    g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    g.fillRect(locx,locy,width,height);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(200,0,45,45);
    g.fillRect(0,100,70,200);

    g.setColor(Color.magenta);
    g.fillRect(200,55,60,135);
}

//update the center rectangle
void updateRectangle() {

    switch (state) {
    case DOWN:
        locy += 2;
        if (locy >= 110) {
        state = UP;
        }
        break;
    case UP:
        locy -= 2;
        if (locy <= 90) {
        state = RIGHT;
        }
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        locx += 2;
        if (locx >= 90) {
        state = LEFT;
        }
        break;
    case LEFT:
        locx -= 2;
        if (locx <= 70) {
        state = DOWN;
        }
        break;
    }
}

public void run() {

    while (true) {
        repaint();  
        updateRectangle();              
        try {
        Thread.sleep (REFRESH_RATE);    
        } catch (Exception exc) { };
    }
}

public void stop() {

    if (animation != null) {
    animation.stop();
    animation = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Swing provides double buffering in most of its components.  You have the source to these components if you want a code example. Look at setDoubleBuffered( ) in JPanel then look at what the code that flag touches does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Double Buffering in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670916/implementing-double-buffering-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `import java.awt.*;`
   Change that to 
   `import javax.swing.*;`
2. `public class Broadway extends Applet ..`

   Change that to 
   `public class Broadway extends JApplet ..`
3. Move all the custom painting into a `JPanel`.  Override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than  `paint(Graphics)`.  *A `JPanel` is double buffered by default.*
4. Do animation using a Swing `Timer`.

### As a general tip

Code a frame & launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) before considering using an applet.

### Update

This code implements most of the advice above, and displays the resulting smooth, buffered animation in an option pane.  It could instead be displayed in a `JFrame` or `JApplet`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Broadway extends JPanel {

    int locx, locy; // location of rectangle
    int width, height; // dimensions of rectangle
    Timer timer;
// direction of motion
    static final byte UP = 0;
    static final byte DOWN = 1;
    static final byte LEFT = 2;
    static final byte RIGHT = 3;
    byte state; // state the rect is in
// length of pausing interval in ms
    static final int REFRESH_RATE = 100;

    public Broadway() {

        setBackground(Color.black);

        locx = 80; // parameters of center rect
        locy = 100;
        width = 110;
        height = 90;
        state = UP;

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
                updateRectangle();
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(this.REFRESH_RATE, listener);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
        g.fillRect(250, 0, 40, 190);
        g.fillRect(80, 110, 100, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(80, 200, 220, 90);
        g.fillRect(100, 10, 90, 80);

        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.fillRect(locx, locy, width, height);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(200, 0, 45, 45);
        g.fillRect(0, 100, 70, 200);

        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.fillRect(200, 55, 60, 135);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

//update the center rectangle
    void updateRectangle() {

        switch (state) {
            case DOWN:
                locy += 2;
                if (locy >= 110) {
                    state = UP;
                }
                break;
            case UP:
                locy -= 2;
                if (locy <= 90) {
                    state = RIGHT;
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                locx += 2;
                if (locx >= 90) {
                    state = LEFT;
                }
                break;
            case LEFT:
                locx -= 2;
                if (locx <= 70) {
                    state = DOWN;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Broadway bw  = new Broadway();

                bw.start();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bw);
                bw.stop();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you replace the paint method so that it paints to an Image the same size as the Applet, then draw that image on `Graphics g`.

There's plenty of implementations out there.

Related questions:

- [Java Double Buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924697/java-double-buffering?rq=1)
- [Double Buffering in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533344/double-buffering-in-java?rq=1)
- [How do you double buffer in java for a game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508042/how-do-you-double-buffer-in-java-for-a-game?rq=1)
- [Java: how to do double-buffering in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing?rq=1)
- [Implementing Double Buffering in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670916/implementing-double-buffering-in-java?rq=1)
- [stop applet flickering with double buffering Java Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232541/stop-applet-flickering-with-double-buffering-java-applet?rq=1)